# Как повернуть объект по направлению к другому через RigidBody.rotation только по оси у?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пробовал через Vector3.RotateTowards и потом его в Quarternion.LookRotatation, и потом беру из этого ось игрик и присваиваю но незнаю как посчитать w. Потому что когда тело падает выводится ошибка

Comment: А что мешает взять только ось y **до** преобразования в кватернион?

Comment: Если известны координаты обоих, то с помощью направленного вектора

Comment: А точнее???????

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц

Comment: @RiotBr3aker как

Comment: Строительство вектор одного объекта к другому по координатам, и потом один объект поворачиваете ровно наоборот с помощью матриц

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поворот объекта через transform.Rotate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890276/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-transform-rotate)