# Поворот объекта через transform.Rotate

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как повернуть объект по направлению к другому через transform.Rotate только по оси у?

Comment: Вторая ссылка в поисковике.  Или же опишите проблему по подробнее.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "повернуть объект по оси y"?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

1. Оказывается, автору нужно вращать RigidBody, а не Transform
2. Видимо, под "вращение по оси y" автор имел в виду "вращение по оси x", т.е. в плоскости yz

---

Получаем вектор между вращающимся объектом и "целью" и передаем его в Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3).

Поскольку нужно вращаться относительно оси Y, нужно оставить `y` составляющую вектора нетронутой, т.е. присвоить ей значение вращающегося объекта.

```
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject target;

    Rigidbody rb;

    void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        Vector3 yz_targetPos = target.transform.position;
        yz_targetPos.x = rb.position.x;
        rb.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(yz_targetPos - rb.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: но transform.rotation будет искажать физику обекта. Даже если менять значения по другим осям на то же самое то объект не может упасть

Comment: @GreenMap, немного не понимаю, вы спросили, цитирую, "Поворот объекта через transform.Rotate", что подразумевает использование transform.rotation. Теперь же вы говорите про физику, простите, но экстрасенсорными способностями я не обладаю - указывайте в вопросе ровно то, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: @GreenMap, что значит "если менять значения по другим осям на то же самое то объект не может упасть". Что вы и где меняете? `transform(rigidbody).rotation` представляют собой матрицу вращения, она никак не может влиять на положение объекта в пространстве (не путать с положением отдельных вершин меши объекта в пространстве).